# Android open PDF from URI starting content

Tags: android, pdf, mime-types

I am trying to open up PDF using intent that takes the following:
Here is the code that I have:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionVIEW)
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("CONTENTURI + FILENAME","application/pdf"
    try { startActivity(intent)} catch excpetion and so on.
```

It pops up with whatever applications I have installed, from Adobe Reader, Google PDF reader, POLARIS(as I am using Galaxy Tab 3 for testing), and none of those work. Each say unsupported document.

Does download and show the right solution in this case, or any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, this will not even compile -- you might have more syntax errors than lines of code. Also, `"CONTENTURI + FILENAME"` is not a valid `Uri`. It is very difficult for people to tell you why your code does not work when you do not post the actual code that does not work.

Comment: @CommonsWare My bad on that, I should've explicit said what the uri was. URL starts with content://+"path to filename". Any ideas on how to work with url that starts with content?

Comment: "URL starts with content://+"path to filename"." -- `content` is a valid scheme, but the rest is not necessarily "path to filename", any more than `/questions/35999407/android-open-pdf-from-uri-starting-content?noredirect=1#comment59680717_35999407` is a path to a filename on the Stack Overflow server. "Any ideas on how to work with url that starts with content?" -- use a `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()`. I wrote [a long blog post about this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

Following code triggers the `VIEW` action for pdf files (open the default PDF viewer, choose between applications capable to view PDFs or get an error if you don't have any installed).

```
    File file = new File("your pdf path here");

    if (file.exists()) {

        Uri pdfPath = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(pdfPath, "application/pdf");

     try {
     startActivity(intent);
      } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
      //if user doesn't have pdf reader instructing to download a pdf reader 
       }   


    }
```

NOTE: The PDF should not be saved local to application, or else the third party app won't have access. You should use `media` location.

Comment: Please add more insight to the OP, on why you posted your code and why it could help him.